# Selecting a P inside a DIV gives error in browser console but in JsFiddle works fine. Why?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, google-chrome-devtools

I'm creating a small thing for practice with JavaScript and I get an error which I can't understand why is happening.

The browser (chrome, firefox) gives me the following error message in the console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null at script.js:12", but when I try the code in JSFiddle everything is working as expected. JavaScript is allowed in the browser, so normally it should work fine.

According to [HTML DOM querySelectorAll() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_queryselectorall.asp) normally, the browser should display correctly the code.

[image: Browser error in console]

The other question is: **How can I avoid typing so many if's? If I want to use a JavaScript switch, how should I write it?**

```js
//find the url of the page
// const findUrl = window.location.href;
const findUrl = "https://www.example.com/en/";
console.log(findUrl);

if (findUrl.match(/en/)) {
  console.log("The match has been found!");
  //select the paragraph inside the div with id #texts
  let findP = document.getElementById("texts").querySelectorAll("p");
  //define a variable with the new text
  let newtxtEN = "A very long text in English to replace the lorem ipsum";
  //replace the lorem ipsum text
  findP[0].innerText = newtxtEN;
}

if(findUrl.match(/fr/)) {
   console.log("The match has been found!");
  //select the paragraph inside the div with id #texts
  let findP = document.getElementById("texts").querySelectorAll("p");
  //define a variable with the new text
  let newtxtFR = "Je ne parle pas français";
  //replace the lorem ipsum text
  findP[0].innerText = newtxtFR;
}

if(findUrl.match(/de/)) {
   console.log("The match has been found!");
  //select the paragraph inside the div with id #texts
  let findP = document.getElementById("texts").querySelectorAll("p");
  //define a variable with the new text
  let newtxtDE = "Ich bin kein Deutscher";
  //replace the lorem ipsum text
  findP[0].innerText = newtxtDE;
}
```

```css
#texts {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: blue;
}
p {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="texts">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Ut,consequuntur.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't say why you are getting that error, but I can say that your approach is extremely out of date and will hurt the performance of your page. If all you are interested in is the first `p` in a given element use `.querySelector("p")` instead of `getElementsByTagName("p")` and then later indexing the result with `[0]`. [**Don't use live node lists.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474)

Comment: Please keep questions to a single topic. Re: `if` statements; don't you just want a simple object with translations, regardless of how that's generated? (Manually, library, ...)

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm quite a beginner but thanks for the tip!

Comment: The accepted answer gets part of the way there, but: since this is a known string, using a regex isn't necessary--you just get the first portion of the URL after the host (e.g., `en`, `de`, etc. That can be used to look it up directly in an object, e.g., `translations[language]`, rather than iterating over an array and doing a regex match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid all the repetitive code using an array of objects.

```js
//find the url of the page
// const findUrl = window.location.href;
const findUrl = "https://www.example.com/en/";
console.log(findUrl);

const langs = [{
    pattern: /en/,
    text: "A very long text in English to replace the lorem ipsum"
  },
  {
    pattern: /fr/,
    text: "Je ne parle pas français"
  },
  {
    pattern: /de/,
    text: "Ich bin kein Deutscher"
  }
];

let found = false;
for (let i = 0; i < langs.length; i++) {
  if (findUrl.match(langs[i].pattern)) {
    console.log("The match has been found!");
    let findP = document.getElementById("texts").querySelectorAll("p");
    findP[0].innerText = langs[i].text;
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
if (!found) {
  console.log("The match was not found");
}
```

```css
#texts {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: blue;
}

p {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="texts">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut,consequuntur.
  </p>
</div>
```

As for why you're getting that error, see [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: I am deeply grateful for the elegant solution provided and the link for explaining why the error was appearing in the browser. I moved the script down near the `</body>` and error disappeared. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

We can't reproduce your issue here and the code works as you intend, so we probably won't be able to give you a concise answer.

However, your code is very outdated and because you are using `.getElementsByTagName()` you are using a "live" node list, which can hurt performance of your page and [really shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474). Additionally, since you are only interested in the first found element within the node list, collecting all the matches only to throw all but the first one away also is a waste.

Lastly, you've got a bunch of duplicated code that need not be there. See the code below for a more proper solution.

```js
//find the url of the page
// const findUrl = window.location.href;
const findUrl = "https://www.example.com/en/";
console.log(findUrl);

let matchFound = "not ";

// You only need to do this once, not in each of your if statements
// since the result isn't going to change. And use .querySelector(),
// not .getElementsByTagName().
let findP = document.getElementById("texts").querySelector("p");

// Instead of 3 separate if statements, use else if so that once you
// have a true condition, the other statemens won't be processed.
if (findUrl.match(/en/)) {
  findP.textContent = "A very long text in English to replace the lorem ipsum";
  matchFound = "";
} else if(findUrl.match(/fr/)) {
  findP.textContent = "Je ne parle pas français";
  matchFound = "";
} else if(findUrl.match(/de/)) {
  findP.textContent = "Ich bi)n kein Deutscher";
  matchFound = "";
}

console.log("The match was " + matchFound + "found.");
```

```css
#texts {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: blue;
}
p {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="texts">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Ut,consequuntur.
  </p>
</div>
```